# Do I need to add 301 redirects when using htaccess to prettify a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I use this simple rule to remove `index.php` from my site's URLs :

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

So that `http://example.com/index.php/user/me` becomes `http://example.com/user/me`.

Do I need to add `[R=301]` to avoid 'content duplication' issues from an SEO point of view?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this rule to avoid that:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

It'll redirect requests made with the `/index.php` in it to the one without. Then the rule that you already have will internally rewrite the index.php back in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Unfortunately, I am unable to wrap my head around this rule (After more than 30 minutes of googling). To be specific, it's the "floating" `\\ ` after the `REQUEST} `, the last `\\ ` in the first line (is that a space?) and finally the `^` of the second line.

Comment: @AhmedSaoudi The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of the HTTP request, which looks something like this: `GET /index.php?something HTTP/1.1`. So the "`\ `"'s are to match the first space. and the last space We need to escape the spaces otherwise apache will assume they are all separate arguments, and not one single regex.

Comment: @AhmedSaoudi the "^" in the rule is simply there to match "anything". Means we don't care what the URI is there, since we've already matched against it in the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable

Answer (score 0):

Just include link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/ on every page and enjoy :).
Read more here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en